# Confusing function call syntax

Tags: go

I am a Golang beginner and I been learning for fews days now. I have learnt a great deal of its syntax and beginning to become comfortable with it. Today I stumbled over a snippet in Go below

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, 
methodsOk)(router)))
```

The `ListernAndServe` has the following signature

```
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error
```

Now the confusing part is the `Handler` paramater in the above server code. Why is the syntax divided like below

```
 handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(router)
```

Is the `(router)` part of the paramater list?

Can someone please breakdown this syntax for me to understand.

Comment: CORS returns a function and you're calling that returned function with the router parameter which then returns a handler and that handler is then finally passed to ListenAndServe. Equivalent to this https://play.golang.com/p/flWHTGXRV58

Comment: see also the api doc, http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/handlers#CORS `func CORS(opts ...CORSOption) func(http.Handler) http.Handler`.

Comment: @mkopriva Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`handlers.CORS`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/handlers#CORS) returns a function and you're calling that function with the router parameter. That function call then returns a handler and that handler is then finally passed to ListenAndServe.

Basically the expression is equivalent to this:

```
f := handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)
h := f(router)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", h))
```